# using jquery to access another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access the data from another javascript file and it's written as such:

```
(function($) {

  var Poller = function () {
    this.defaults = {
      type: 'veggies',
      limit: 10
    };

    this.items = {
      veggies: [
        'Adzuki Beans',
        'Asparagus',
        'Black-eyed Peas',
        'Brussels Sprouts',
        'Carrots',
        'Collard Greens',
        'Parsnips',
        'Rhubarb',
        'Yams',
        'Watercress'
      ],
      fruits: [
        'Apricots',
        'Blackcurrants',
        'Cherimoya',
        'Dates',
        'Elderberry',
        'Guava',
        'Kumquat',
        'Miracle Fruit',
        'Purple Mangosteen',
        'Satsuma'
      ]
    };
  };

  Poller.prototype._getRandomNumber = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  Poller.prototype._getData = function (type) {
    var item, i, len;
    var list = this.items[type] || [];
    var results = [];

    for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
      item = list[i];

      results.push({
        name: item,
        count: this._getRandomNumber(0, 200000)
      });
    }
    return results;
  };

  Poller.prototype._processData = function (data, limit) {
    return data.slice(0, limit);
  };

  Poller.prototype.poll = function (options, cb) {
    var self = this;
    var config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
      var payload = self._processData(self._getData(config.type), config.limit);

      cb && cb(payload);      
      dfd.resolve(payload);
    }, this._getRandomNumber(400, 2000));

    return dfd;
  };

  if (window.spredfast == null) {
    window.spredfast = {
      Poller: Poller
    };
  }
}(jQuery));
```

In the HTML it's embedded just before my script file, meaning,

```
<script src="api.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

How do I go about accessing the data from my script file and display it in descending order mixing veggies and fruits?

Thanks,

Comment: you need to create a `Poller` instance. what code do you have now that you attemtped to access the script

Comment: Hi Bill, 

I've tried var obj = window.Poller; 

              var obj = window.spreadfast.Poller;

Comment: Do you have access to change the file?

Comment: Yes, the api.js file resides in the same folder as my script.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work...

```
if (!(spredfast in window)) {
  window.spredfast = {
      Poller: function(){
        return new PollerInstance();
      }
  };
} else {
  window.spredfast.Poller = function(){
    return new PollerInstance();
  };
}

// call
var Poller = spredfast.Poller();
```

Comment: Thanks, the code returns, Uncaught ReferenceError: Poller is not defined

Comment: @kirdua whoops, my mistake. you can instantiate Poller within your self invoking function because Poller does not exist yet. Updated..

Answer (score 0):

Run this, to access the data items.veggies for example. A new instance of Poller had to be created.

```js
(function($) {

  var Poller = function () {
    
    this.defaults = {
      type: 'veggies',
      limit: 10
    };

    this.items = {
      veggies: [
        'Adzuki Beans',
        'Asparagus',
        'Black-eyed Peas',
        'Brussels Sprouts',
        'Carrots',
        'Collard Greens',
        'Parsnips',
        'Rhubarb',
        'Yams',
        'Watercress'
      ],
      fruits: [
        'Apricots',
        'Blackcurrants',
        'Cherimoya',
        'Dates',
        'Elderberry',
        'Guava',
        'Kumquat',
        'Miracle Fruit',
        'Purple Mangosteen',
        'Satsuma'
      ]
    };
  };

  Poller.prototype._getRandomNumber = function (min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  };

  Poller.prototype._getData = function (type) {
    var item, i, len;
    var list = this.items[type] || [];
    var results = [];

    for (i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
      item = list[i];

      results.push({
        name: item,
        count: this._getRandomNumber(0, 200000)
      });
    }
    return results;
  };

  Poller.prototype._processData = function (data, limit) {
    return data.slice(0, limit);
  };

  Poller.prototype.poll = function (options, cb) {
    var self = this;
    var config = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
      var payload = self._processData(self._getData(config.type), config.limit);

      cb && cb(payload);      
      dfd.resolve(payload);
    }, this._getRandomNumber(400, 2000));

    return dfd;
  };

  if (window.spredfast == null) {
    
    window.spredfast = {
      Poller: new Poller()
    };
  }
}(jQuery));


var dfd = window.spredfast.Poller.poll().then(function(data) {
  
  data.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.count < b.count;
  });
  
  var message = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    message += data[i].name + ': ' + data[i].count + '\n';
  }
  
  alert(message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thx for the info. how do I access that from a new script though and trigger the function?

Comment: depends on what you to access, but this example you could use window.spredfast.Poller.items.veggies[0]

Comment: I'm trying to access both fruits and veggies, plus the random number assigned to them and display them in descending order.

Comment: I updated the code above, use the promise that is returned

window.spredfast.Poller.poll().then()

Comment: The last several lines in above example use an alert to display the first veggie. It returns an array of veggies with the random values.
If you want fruits, you would have to change the default option where it shows type: 'veggies' in Poller.

Comment: thx for the help. another question i'm trying to sort using the random number. I've been trying to associate data[i].count with a variable and then trying to sort except i keep returning errors.

 var veg = data[i].count;
 veg.sort(function(a,b){return b - a});

Comment: Updated above code to add sort.
return a.count < b.count;